# How can I make IntelliJ/Android Studio open Android docs when clicking F1 on function?

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Let's say I have the following line of Android code:

```
MyClass myClass = (MyClass) intent.getExtras().getSerializable("SomeKey");
```

How can I make IntelliJ/Android Studio open a browser and navigate to the following URI when hitting F1 while the cursor has marked "getSerializable"?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getSerializable(java.lang.String)

Is there a plugin for this maybe?

Comment: added tag `intellij-plugin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open up `Project Structure` window and then go to `Libraries` and point to the android jar:

[image]

Now press the green plus sign:

[image]

Choose the `Specify Documentation URL...` option:

[image]

Enter the Android SDK API url:

[image]

Press `OK` all the way back so you end up in the editor again. Now place the caret at the method and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>:

[image]

The browser will open up and navigate to the correct page.

Comment: What to do if "Libraries" is not shown under Project Structure? My android.jar is in "External Libraries" in the project tree.

Answer (score 3):

In my Android Studio 1.5.1 installation, the libraries are listed in the `Structure View` once I select my module from the `Project View` and select `Android` from the drop-down as shown in this link:

[Click >> Project View and Project Structure View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvLYd.png)

Now right-clink on the library you want to add URL to and select `Library Properties`. A window will popup with a button `Specify Documentation URL` and you can paste your URL there.

[Click >> Library Properties windows and Documentation URL popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Six48.png)

Now you can go to the code editor, select any element you want to see documentation for and press `Shift+F1` and browser will open up with the corresponding URL.

Comment: It works on Android Studio 2.1.1 too, just to get there the code editor must be empty (otherwise you will see the class structure instead of the libraries). The previous solution with "Project Stricture" doesn't work any more.

Comment: It could have been the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately "Library Properties" exists for anything else but the Android Platform library.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1

Select an Android SDK symbol (e.g. class name) and then...

Press `Shift+F1` to open browser with External Documentation

Press `Ctrl+Q` to open a popup showing Quick Documentation

[image]