# How to set up external documentation in Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I would like to make <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (show external documentation) work.
I am aware of this question:
[How can I make IntelliJ/Android Studio open Android docs when clicking F1 on function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836967/how-can-i-make-intellij-android-studio-open-android-docs-when-clicking-f1-on-fun)

But my project structure is entierly different (ie. Libraries section is missing!)

[image: Project Structure]

How can I set up external documentation location in Android Studio 1.1.0? 
Ie. for Android Support Library, Google Play Services, etc.

**EDIT:**
The external doc for the Android SDK is already working, but I can't for example change it to an online version, and I can't set it for Play Services and Support Library at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repeating the comment from above as an answer, as requested:

Unfortunately, Android Studio has manipulated the IntelliJ settings IDE, so you cannot provide an external link in the UI to documentation. Normally the module settings (or Project Structure) would have the ability to look at all libraries and configure where to find external docs. If you are feeling brave, you could try manually by going to `~/.idea/libraries` and edit `play_services_x_y_z.xml` (x, y and z are the version numbers you are using.) Look for the `<JAVADOC />` tag. Modify it to be `<JAVADOC>` and add a sub tag `<root url="put_your_external_url_here" />` then close the javadoc tag.

You should be able to create a custom gradle task to inject the appropriate XML if the file ever changes so it prevents issues on gradle sync.  But, it would be some work.  It's really a function of how IntelliJ handles maven dependencies from within Gradle and the setup of its projects rather than it being gradle's fault, so I don't think there's any special gradle setting to make it work.

Comment: Only internal documentation is working for me but not the external one. Under my "~" directory, I'm not able to find the .idea/libraries file. Does it have a different location where it could be found? My SDK location is: Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk and JDK location is /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: @RedM it's continued to change as Android Studio has evolved. On OS X, settings are stored in `$HOME/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio4.0` (though the trailing version may be different for you - depends on what you have installed!) Look in the `options/jdk.table.xml` file. There will be a number of JDKs defined in there, under the one you are using you should find a `<javadocPath>` tag and a root URL setting. You should be able to modify this as needed.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still a bit lost. I made it to the file jdk.table.xml, however when searching for "jdk1.8.0_45" which is my current in use jdk version, there are 30 matches in that file alone. Also, when searching for "javadocPath", there are 112 matches. How do I know which one to modify, and what should I add/remove/edit exactly to it? Thank you Larry.

Comment: Look for the JDK which is part of the platform API you are targeting - though it may be best just to modify the latest (API 29) entry. That's really where AS is going to pull things from.

Comment: I went to tag "jdk", under where there is tag "name" with the value "Android API 29 Platform", then I scrolled down to "javadocPath" tag (while still being under the jdk parent tag). I added this: "<root url="https://developer.android.com" type="simple" />" under <root type="composite"> , restarted Android Studio, be unfortunately, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Go into your Android SDK (Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager) and make sure the "Documentation for Android SDK" is installed for the target version of Android you are building against (see the Android 5.1 (API 22) section):

[image: Android SDK Manager]

Comment: The external doc for the SDK is working, but I can't for example change it, and I can't set it for Play Services and Support Library

Comment: Unfortunately, Android Studio has manipulated the IntelliJ settings IDE, so you cannot provide an external link in the UI to documentation.  Normally the module settings (or Project Structure) would have the ability to look at all libraries and configure where to find external docs.  If you are feeling brave, you could try manually by going to ~/.idea/libraries and edit play_services_x_y_z.xml (x, y and z are the version #s you are using.)  Look for the <JAVADOC /> tag.  Modify it to be <JAVADOC> and add a sub tag <root url="put_your_external_url_here" /> then close the javadoc tag.

Comment: Thanks, that actually did work! The only problem left is that it gets deleted on a gradle sync (which isn't very surprising of course). But since ist an ok sollution (/hack), if you make a separate answer for that, you will get the bounty if no better solution comes in a few days. Although I wish there was a way to put it in a gradle build file somehow.

Comment: ...or something to prevent it from being deleted on a gradle sync.